# Screen not re rendering on fetching rtk query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rtk-query

I am new to RTK query. I was implementing pull to refresh in which I am trying to call the GET API again on pull to refresh.
API result is getting logged successfully but it is not refreshing the screen or returning updated response.
I am using it as below.

```
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false)
  const [
    getListing,
    { data, isLoading, isError, error },
  ] = useLazyListingQuery()

  useEffect(() => {
    getListing('1')
  }, [])

  const fetchList = () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true)
    getListing('1')
  }
```

and below is my flatlist component

```
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={useCallback((item, index: number) => 'key' + index, [])}
        removeClippedSubviews
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        windowSize={8}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
        ListHeaderComponent={renderSeparator}
        ListFooterComponent={renderSeparator}
        onRefresh={fetchList}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
      />
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about just the normal query hook?

```
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isError, error, refetch} = useListingQuery()

      <FlatList
        data={data}
        // ...
        onRefresh={refetch}
        refreshing={isFetching}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how refresh works for me (leaving out most of the stuff you've already worked out). I think you're missing the RefreshControl component.

```js
    import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl } from "react-native";
    import { useGetBooksForListQuery } from "../../store/bookSlice";

    export default function EditSeries({ route, navigation }) {

    /**
     * refresh control
     */
    const [ refreshing, setRefreshing ] = useState(false);
    
    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
        setRefreshing(true);
        refetchBooks();
        setTimeout(() => {
          setRefreshing(false);
        }, 2000);
      }, []);

    /**
     * get books in series
     */

    const {
        data: books = [],
        isLoading: isLoadingBooks,
        refetch: refetchBooks,
        isFetching: isFetchingBooks,
        isSuccess: isSuccessBooks,
        isError: isErrorBooks,
        error: errorBooks,
    } = useGetBooksForListQuery(series.id);

    return (
        <View style={GeneralStyles.screen}>
            <FlatList
                data={books}
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
                }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```